# SQL Server 2008 - How do I add a constraint that prevents the same value from appearing in both Column A and Column B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two `varchar` columns (`ColA, ColB`) in a single table (`Table1`)

Is there a way to craft a constraint that would prevent the same value from appearing in both `ColA` and `ColB`?

## Example

---

**Original Table**:

```
-----------------------
| Col A    |   Col B  |
-----------------------
| Alice    |   Bob    |
-----------------------
```

**Insert Command that I would like to fail**

```
Insert into Table1 values ('Bob', 'Jill')
```

**Undesired Result**

```
-----------------------
| ColA     |   ColB   |
-----------------------
| Alice    |   Bob    |   <-- Bob In Col B
-----------------------
| Bob      |   Jill   |   <-- Bob in Col A
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to implement this constraint logic as a [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

@Mitch Wheat is correct.

**Here's some working code:**

```
ALTER TRIGGER TABLE1_Check_Two_Col_Uniqueness ON TABLE1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF  EXISTS      (   SELECT 1 FROM Table1 as T1 inner join inserted as I on I.ColA = T1.ColB )
        OR EXISTS   (   SELECT 1 FROM Table1 as T1 inner join inserted as I on I.ColB = T1.ColA )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Error Inserting Table1_Record, it would cause a duplicate ColA and ColB', 16, 1)
            RETURN
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Table1
            SELECT
                ColA, 
                ColB
            FROM
                inserted
        END
END
```